# git hook - Not a git repository: '.git'

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, githooks

I create a hook(post-commit) which run *.bat* file and in this file make push to current brach. When I run *.bat* manually it works fine but when it start by hook it throws exception.

"current dir"(working dir) is same in both cases.

post-commit

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./.git/hooks
start post-commit.bat
```

post-commit.bat

```
@ECHO OFF                               

Echo Current dir: "%CD%"

set /p yn=Push to current brach immediately[Y/N]? 
if "%yn%"=="y" goto y 
if "%yn%"=="n" goto n 
if "%yn%"=="Y" goto y 
if "%yn%"=="N" goto n 
goto error 
:error 
cls 
echo That is not a recognized choice. 
pause 
exit 
:y 
echo Starting push...
git push
pause
exit 
:n 
exit
```

.bat output

```
Current dir: "c:\Users\Dan\Documents\Ambro\Areus\_Areus - Employee - PC\_Areus -
 Employee - PC\.git\hooks"

Push to current brach immediately[Y/N]? y
Starting push...
fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of insomnia I solved it. I must a little bit edit a hook.

post-commit

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./.git/hooks || exit
unset GIT_DIR
start post-commit.bat
```